# add subview is not displaying my uiview

Tags: objective-c, addsubview

I have the following code, and the uiview is not showing, i've placed a breakpoint & see the view is not nil and the frame is set to the given size - why the view is not showing in my uiviewcontroller?

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) LoadingView *loadingView;

self.loadingView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LoadingView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
self.loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(110,170,100,100);

[self.view addSubview:self.loadingView];
```

Comment: where do you add the view? are you sure that self.view is already loaded?

Comment: @tadasz in one of my methods

Answer (score 0):

Your code is logically wrong. Your LoadingView class must allocate before you assigning nib member to it.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LoadingView" owner:self options:nil];
        self = [nibs objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Your nib assignment should be in the initwithframe method of `LoadingView` class.
Then Your implementation of adding view would be like,

```
self.loadingView = [[LoadingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110,170,100,100)];
[self.view addSubview:self.loadingView];
```